# React Native App crashing in testflight due to react native nagvigation issue. cant resolve issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I have an application that I have build and I am currently in the process of building and uploading to Apple for submission. It would **instantly crash when loading in Testflight**.

I wanted to see what was causing the issue so **I created a generic default react native application with nothing done to it**. When i built it and submitted it to Apple and ran the default react native app, **it ran perfectly and loaded up on Testflight**.

I then went in and **added a bottom tab navigation and each tab in the bottom tab navigation was connected to a stack navigation**. I created 4 screens which are `HomeScreen, FeedScreen, FavoritesScreen, and ProfileScreen`.

Just adding the navigation system to my default react native application **causes my app to immediately crash upon loading in Testflight**.

Does anyone know why the navigation structure is causing Testflight crashing?

Code:

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import BottomTabNavigation from './src/navigation/BottomTabNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <BottomTabNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

BottomTabNavigation.js:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"
import { Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons'

import HomeStackNavigation from "./HomeStackNavigation";
import FavoritesStackNavigation from "./FavoritesStackNavigation";
import FeedStackNavigation from "./FeedStackNavigation";
import ProfileStackNavigation from "./ProfileStackNavigation";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='PropertiesScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Properties" 
        key='Properties'
        component={HomeStackNavigation} 
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"home"} color={color} size={size} />)
        }}/>
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Favorites" 
        key='Favorites'
        component={FavoritesStackNavigation} 
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"heart"} color={color} size={size} />)
        }}/>
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Feed"
        key='Feed'
        component={FeedStackNavigation} 
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"menu"} color={color} size={size} />)
        }}/>
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Profile"
        key='Profile'
        component={ProfileStackNavigation} 
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"user"} color={color} size={size} />)
        }}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default BottomTabNavigation
```

FavoritesStackNavigation.js:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';

const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

const FavoritesStackNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: true}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="FavoritesScreen" component={FavoritesScreen}/>
    </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

export default FavoritesStackNavigation
```

Each of the stack navigation has the same exact setups as the one above.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rippe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I just want to find out why the navigation system I have is causing the Testflight crash.

Comment: does the crash happen when you build locally?  have you tried building in Xcode?  you'll get better crash logs

Comment: I always built the app with react native and expo. Never ran it on Xcode. It builds perfectly locally @Abe

Comment: it could be because of the initialRouteName, it should be Properties not PropertiesScreen. but as Abe said you better get crash logs